# On post-back dynamically added controls are replaced

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay, so I have a table on my ASP page like so:

```
<asp:Table ID="attachedFiles" runat="server" BorderColor="LightGray" BorderWidth="1" ViewStateMode="Enabled"> 
    <asp:TableRow ID = "attachedFilesRow" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="exampleCell" runat="server" Visible="false" >
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" />
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/images/kill.png" OnClick="removeAttachment" />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

The example cell I create here is not visible because I am only using it as a template for other cells that I will be adding in the code behind:

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
TableRow row = new TableRow(); 

cell = exampleCell;
row = attachedFilesRow;

((Label)cell.Controls[0]).Text = fileName;
cell.Visible = true;
row.Cells.Add(cell);
attachedFilesRow = row;
attachedFilesRow.DataBind();
```

The code in the code behind is in an onClick method for a button on the ASP page. The idea is that if the user wants to add an attachment, they click 'Add attachment' and then a cell is added to the already existing table. The cell is supposed to look like this [filenName.txt X] where the X is an ImageButton so that the user can click it and delete the attachment.

My problem is that everytime the user adds an attachment, the previous TableCell is replaced with the new TableCell instead of added to the TableRow. I thought that maybe it was because I was creating a TableCell and then setting it to equal an already existing table cell instance so I tried this:

ASP:

```
<asp:Table ID="attachedFiles" runat="server" BorderColor="LightGray" BorderWidth="1" ViewStateMode="Enabled"> 
    <asp:TableRow ID = "attachedFilesRow" runat="server">
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Code Behind:

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();

ImageButton button = new ImageButton();
button.ImageUrl = "~/images/kill.png";
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "removeAttachment");

Label label = new Label();
label.Text = fileName;

cell.Controls.Add(button);
cell.Controls.Add(label);

attachedFilesRow.Cells.Add(cell);
```

I have also tried both ways with adding attachedFilesRow.DataBind(); to the end and have tried both methods with instantiating new Row and Cell Objects istead of just directly using existing ones from the ASP page. Neither of those things seems to play much of a role.

**tl;dr** Every time I add a TableCell to my existing table on buttonClick, it replaces the other cell in my table instead of adding to it.

EDIT:

I don't necessarily want to add a new Row... This is what I want:

After the user adds one attachment: [fileName.txt X]

After two: [fileName.txt X] [fileName2.txt X]

After three: [fileName.txt X][fileName2.txt X][fileName3.txt X]

It's basically a on Row table, adding columns or cells if that makes sense.

Comment: You need to modify attachedFiles in the codebehind instead of attachedFileRow.  You need to add rows to the table instead of cells to the the tablerow. Like @Pete's answer, reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Guys, think you're going down the wrong route. The reason it is not appearing and seems to be replaced is your dynamically created control is being LOST! Please check my answer out for a link that expands on what I mean!

Comment: Yeah, I used the advice from Pete and Michael_B and am still getting the same issue even though I'm creating and adding an entire row everytime instead of just a Cell. I'm going to look into your answer, Belogix. Will report back.

Comment: I've added some code to clarify my comments.

Answer (score 1):

You are not "**Replacing**" the previous cell. On each post-back the [ASP.NET page life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) kicks in and you will get a new instance of the page. This is because the web is stateless and although ASP.NET gives the impression of state it doesn't really exist.

So, what is happening is you are starting from scratch each time, you are always creating one cell in your row. What you need to do is keep a list of all the items you have added and then render them (via data-binding or code) each time.

This sample should do **EXACTLY** what you want:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private const string UploadViewState = "UploadViewState";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // initialise list and store in ViewState
                ViewState[UploadViewState] = new List<string>();
            }
        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the list from ViewState and add the new item
            var _filesToUpload = (List<string>)ViewState[UploadViewState];
            _filesToUpload.Add(text1.Text);

            // Now recreate the row adding cells for each file...
            foreach (string item in _filesToUpload)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                ImageButton button = new ImageButton();
                button.ImageUrl = "~/images/kill.png";
                button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "removeAttachment");
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = item;
                cell.Controls.Add(button);
                cell.Controls.Add(label);
                attachedFilesRow.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to my code sample you could use **Data-Binding** on the `List<...>` of files but I was just following on from your code. The secret is to use a `List<...>` of items and store in the ViewState, from that point on everything else should be simple.